# Spring @Autowired Interface conditional resolution at runtime via CLI

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and annotations in general. I have an Interface (ApiClientInterface) that I'd like to use the `@Autowired` annotation on a property to resolve. For the sake of this post, assume I have two implementations...

Implementation one:

```
package com.java.app.apiclient;

@Component
class HttpRestAdapter implements ApiClient {
    ...
}
```

Implementation two:

```
package com.java.app.apiclient;

@Component
class FakeAdapter implements ApiClient {
    ...
}
```

I did some googling and found the `@Qualifier` annotation, but I'm not sure this is the right path, because this is a CLI application. Ideally, something like this would be possible:

```
$ java -jar myjar --apiclient=fake
$ #  - OR -
$ java -jar myjar --apiclient=resthttp
```

Depending on the value of that `--apiclient` argument, ideally the IoC container would know which implementation to resolve. In other words, I'd like this test to pass:

```
public class ApiServiceFactoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApiClient client;

    @Test
    public void testClientResolution() {
        assertEquals(client.getClass(), isA(FakeClient.class));
    }
}
```

I am coming from the PHP world where the IoC Container bindings are more commonly registered explicitly in ServiceProviders where something like a factory could be used to determine which implementation should be registered. I'd like to stick with annotating & injecting the interface, rather than injecting a factory and then using that factory to get the correct service.

In Spring's case, the annotations are "hard coded", so it's not possible to do that resolution programmatically (at least not that I can find). So, how can I allow the container to resolve the implementation at runtime? Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeanFactory` based injection.

```
@Component
public class Application {

  private final ApplicationClient appClient;

  public Application((@Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory) {
       appClient = beanFactory.getBean(beanName, ApplicationClient.class)
  }

}
```

For testing I would strongly suggest using [Spring Testing Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html)

Comment: I appreciate the response. That does seem like it would work, but I don't love the idea of the `ApplicationClient` being aware of that much about the container bindings. I'm curious what the general best practices are here when it comes to Spring. Mixing concerns with the Service Locator in this matter feels a bit like an anti-patter.

Comment: Looked at your implementation. You don't need to create your own factory. Spring context is the bean factory and will be autowired if you ask to autowire the BeanFactory. So code above should be enough to achieve this

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it seems that implementation would require the `ApiService` to know about the `BeanFactory` (i.e. the IoC container) and how to retrieve the binding it needs. I feel that's mixing concerns a little more than I'd like to for this particular use case, and perhaps more importantly makes testing a little more tricky. Feel free to correct me if I misunderstand. Thanks again for taking the time to review and respond!

Comment: I don't see how this is mixed, but if all you trying to achieve is starting different profiles - take a look at Spring profiles https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html By setting a different profile (on command line) you will be able to affect your configuration

Comment: I think swapping the Profile based on CLI arguments might be more on the path of what I was looking for, if a little overkill. I'll have to dig into that when I get near a computer again.

Answer (score 0):

After a rather embarrassing struggle, I finally figured out how to accomplish this using a [`FactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean). This [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean) from Baeldung was a big help in getting there. Here is what I ended up with.

First, I created a `FactoryBean`, or more accurately, extended `AbstractFactoryBean`.

```
package com.java.app.apiclient;

@Component
public class ApiClientFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<ApiClient> {

    @Autowired
    private FakeAdapter fakeAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private HttpRestAdapter httpRestAdapter;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ApiClient.class;
    }

    @Override
    public ApiClient createInstance() {
        // Conditionally return the appropriate implementation. 
        // For now, force the noop flavor for demonstration purposes.
        return fakeAdapter;
    }
}
```

Now that I had a factory, I needed a way to tell Spring to use that factory when an instance of `ApiClient` was being resolved. This can be accomplished by way of xml files, but more importantly (for me at least) Java classes using the `@Configuration` annotation.

```
package package com.java.app.config;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    // The name argument to the `@Bean` annotation here makes it so we
    // can access the value with a `@Qualifier` annotation
    @Bean(name = "apiClient")
    public ApiClient ApiClient () {
        return ApiClientFactory().createInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiClientFactory apiClientFactory() {
        return new ApiClientFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public FakeAdapter fakeAdapter() {
        return new FakeAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpRestAdapter httpRestAdapter () {
        return new HttpRestAdapter();
    }
}
```

Lastly when it came time to grab the instance from the container, it was as simple as:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("apiClient")
    private ApiClient api;
}
```

That seems to the trick! Quite possible there is a "better" or more idiomatic way but this fulfills my requirement of "pushing" from the IoC container, rather than "pulling" via `BeanFactory`.